# How to stop multiple toolbars appearing in PyQt5 when switching between MatPlotLib Graphs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I move between two graphs via a button (I hide the previous window and replace it with a different equation for the graph). At the moment, each time I switch between the graphs, instead of removing the toolbar from the previous graph it instead builds up with each button press. I cannot seem to remove the previous toolbar (automatically generated by MatPlotLib) even though a new window is being created.

I have attempted to change the order when I believe the toolbar is added however I cannot find a point at which it removes the previous toolbar, but still generates a new one.

def Draw_Graph(self):

```
self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.Graph, self))  
    if self.Graph_Type==1:  
        self.Axis = self.Graph.figure.subplots()  
        print(type(self.V_Initial_V))  
        x = np.linspace(0, self.Time, 501)  
        self.Axis.plot(x, (x*self.V_Acceleration)+self.V_Initial_V)  
    elif self.Graph_Type==2:  
        self.Axis = self.Graph.figure.subplots()  
        x = np.linspace(0, self.Time, 501)  
        self.Axis.plot(x, -(self.V_Acceleration/2)*(x**2))
```

Ideally, it should remove the previous toolbar and only include the toolbar for the current graph.

Comment: Each time you call `Draw_Graph()` you add a new toolbar. If that is undesired, simply don't do it.

Comment: Hi, are you implying that I should find a new way to change the axis outside of this particular procedure, or to change the location of the line: self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.Graph, self)) .

Comment: It seems you you can work with the same figure throughout and hence only ever use a single toolbar.

Comment: I know I only need a single tool bar, but only one graph appears on the page at a single time, and each time the graph is viewed another tool bar is added, even going back to the same graph adds a new tool bar next to the previous until it becomes almost impossible to use. I can't seem to get the program to only use one.

Comment: `self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.Graph, self))` adds a new toolbar, so what you describe is expected. Put that line whereever you define `self.Graph.figure` in your code instead.